# Runserver: " Not Found: / "

Tags: django, frameworks, server

I executed runserver to test Django Framework but it appears a message " `Not Found: /` ". When I try the page `localhost:8000` it works fine, but the message is still there. Any idea?

P.S. I tried `localhost:8000/admin` and the message does not appear.

[image]

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Can you post your urls.py?

Comment: I just started the project now. I didn't even modified anything on the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens simply because you didn't define any pattern in `urls.py` that matches `/` and you have some views that matches `admin/`.

If you want to show something in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` you will need to create a view first and add it to `urls.py` like

```
`url(r'^$', 'myview', name='myview'),``
```

I recommend you to follow the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: You were right. I started a new app and defined a new url for the / and I no longer got the message anymore. I just wondered why I've never got this before and now, starting a new project, it appeared. Anyway, thanks for your help.